# Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined when setState for coordinate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

In the picture, I want to get lat and lng to `setState` but somehow get the error "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined". I'm newbie so I don't know why. I hope everyone can fix and explain more

Comment: please don't post pictures of code; paste it into the question instead.

Comment: short answer - use an arrow function inside the `.then`

Comment: [There's probably a better duplicate that's more specific to this question, but this was the first I found, and goes into great detail about the relevant differences between arrow function and `function` declarations] Does this answer your question? [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the function inside of .then() and name it.

```
function thenFn(result) { .... }
```

Now you can bind ‘this’ to whatever you need it too with:

```
.then(thenFn.bind(this))
```

EDIT

As specified by commenters, you can fix this much more elegantly with an arrow function. All you need to do for that is to change:

```
.then(function (result) { .... })
```

To

```
.then((result) => { .... })
```

Essentially just remove ‘function’ and add an arrow between the parameters and brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access `this.setState` inside an anonymous function. It seems that the function is not bound to a context which has the `setState` method. Using an arrow function would solve this problem.

```
.then(result => {

   ....

   this.setState ...

)
```

---

The `this` keyword inside a function is bound to the calling context. But arrow functions don't have its own `this` context and if used, it would refer to the parent context;

Helpful links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions